# QGIS & GeoMedia .mdb .gws compatibility?

Tags: qgis, geomedia

i cannot open Geomedia file directly from QGIS 1.8.0! Gdal driver >= 1.9.0

reference is made to below link

[qgis-connecting-geomedia-mdb-warehouse](http://furiousgis.blogspot.com/2012/05/qgis-connecting-geomedia-mdb-warehouse.html)

anyone have any experience in using GeoMedia file in QGIS???

Comment: Dead link, this might be the same one: http://gistncase.blogspot.ca/2012/05/qgis-connecting-geomedia-mdb-warehouse.html

Answer (score 1):

You can open .mdb file with QGIS 1.8.0, but not all type of Geomedia feature class are supported.
Add vector layer -> Browse -> select from type file "ESRI Personal Geodatabase [OGR] .mdb .MDB"

Comment: Yup, try that but with no luck, received error "invalid data source", but my GeoMedia file can be opened with ArcGIS with FME plug-in directly.

Comment: Try to explore on the [Geomedia MDB database GDAL/OGR >= 1.9.0](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_geomedia.html) page but have no idea how to start. further instruction and recommendation are most welcomed.